# Subset of File between two dates, when some dates are invalid

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, timestamps

I have come across several similar questions, but the solutions seem to be failing me, and I believe it is because I have some junk data in my file that is breaking my attempt to filter by time stamp.

Here is an example file:

```
2020-12-12 12:10:00,3,4,2
2020-12-12 12:11:00,4,3,2
2020-12-12 12:12:00,4,3,2
2020-12-12 12:13:00,4,3,2
20-12-12 12:14:00,4,3,2
4,3,2
2020-12-12 12:16:00,4,3,1
-12-12 12:17:00,4,3,2
2020-12-12 12:18:00,5,3,2
```

I'd like to filter this file, creating a new file only containing valid time stamps (each line should start with a valid time stamp).

```
BegDate="2020-12-12 12:11:00"
EndDate="2020-12-12 12:16:00"
```

I've tried using sed

```
TimeWindow=$(sed -rne '/'$BegDate'/,/'$EndDate'/p' $MyFile)
echo $TimeWindow > NewFile.csv
```

and awk

```
awk -v from=$BegTime -v to=$EndTime '$1>=from && $1<=to' "$MyFile" > "NewFile.csv"
```

But both are failing

The desired result for "NewFile.csv" is

```
2020-12-12 12:11:00,4,3,2
2020-12-12 12:12:00,4,3,2
2020-12-12 12:13:00,4,3,2
2020-12-12 12:16:00,4,3,1
```

Comment: This gives the output in your example, but I would look into the refined answers below. `awk -F, -v from="$BegDate" -v to="$EndDate" '$1>=from && $1<=to' "$MyFile"`

Comment: I can't understand how you can compare dates with `<`,`>`,`<=` or `>=` with out translating it to an epoch timestamp. For doing that you need an OO programming languages.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini, here `<=`/`>=` do lexicographical (string) comparisons, not number comparisons. And with that `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` timestamp format, lexicographical order is the same as chronological order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve you `awk` approach by also checking that the first field follows a valid date format.

```
LC_ALL=C awk -F, -v from="$BegTime" -v to="$EndTime" '
  BEGIN {valid = "^" from "$"; gsub("[0-9]", "[0-9]", valid)}
  $1 ~ valid && $1 >= from && $1 <= to'
```

Above the regexp to validate dates is built from `$BegTime` by replacing digits in it with `[0-9]` (which in the C locale is the same as `[0123456789]`) and adding `^` at the start and `$` at the end for anchoring at start and end.

You could refine the regexp if you also wanted to exclude invalid dates such as 9999-99-99 99:99:99 or 2022-02-29 00:00:00.

Make sure you quote all shell parameter expansions (see how your code matches one of the examples at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)). Also note the discrepancy between `BegTime` and `BegDate` in your question.